# Register to Eureka from Docker with a custom IP

Tags: docker, netflix-eureka

I'm running Spring Cloud Eureka inside my Docker VM. I have services registering to it, but they use their IP adress from inside the Docker VM, but to be able to use them properly i need them to use the IP adress i can access from outside the VM.

For example inside my VM the register using 172.x.x.x and i can access the REST interface from my browser using 192.168.x.x.x. I need them to register as 192.168.x.x.x.

How can i tell my service to register with a specific IP adress?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure it in your `application.yml`:

```
eureka:
    instance:
        ipAddress: 192.168.x.x
```

Comment: That's fine, but what if IP changes dynamically each time? I want to expose host IP, not the container.

Comment: If the host's IP change dynamically then pass this IP to the container in an environment variable and use this variable in the Spring config.

Comment: That's the question, how do I pass host IP address inside container using AWS BeansTalk service?

Answer (score 11):

Both previous answers are correct, but I'll make copy-pasting easier.

What you should do is add an environment variable with the host IP when starting your container and in your Spring Boot `application.yml` file includes it.

**application.yml**

```
eureka:
  instance:
    # Necessary for Docker as it doesn't have DNS entries
    prefer-ip-address: true
    # Necessary for Docker otherwise you will get 172.0.0.x IP
    ip-address: "${HOST}"
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      # Location of your eureka server
      defaultZone: http://192.168.0.107:8761/eureka/
```

**Running with Docker**

```
docker run -p <port>:<port> -e HOST='192.168.0.106' <image name>
```

**Running with docker-compose**

```
my_service:
  image: image_name
  environment:
    - HOST=192.168.0.106
  ports:
    - your_port:container_port
```

Comment: How should I do in the docker-compose to set the host of other service defined there?

Answer (score 1):

Register to Eureka with a custom IP and a custom PORT:

```
server:
  port: 18090
eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
    ip-address: 10.150.160.21
    non-secure-port: 8080
```

I run into a situation where 10.150.160.21:8080 is mapped to 192.168.1.124:18090 over a firewall. The application is running on 192.168.1.124:18090 but have to register to Eureka with 10.150.160.21:8080.

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables in the eureka configuration in application.yml

In the following example I am using the `$HOST` and `$PORT` environment variables to tell the eureka client what values to use. In my case, these variables are set by Mesos/Marathon. You may find other useful variables set by Docker.

The following works for me:

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
       defaultZone: http://discovery.marathon.mesos:31444/eureka/
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
  instance:
    appname: configserver
    health-check-url: /health
    prefer-ip-address: true
    ip-address: "${HOST}" # mesos/marathon populates this in the environment
    non-secure-port: "${PORT}" # mesos/marathon populates this in the environment
```