# Eureka service always registers instances with host name even though i put "prefer-ip-address: true"

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

I want to register my micro services in Eureka with the IP address instead of host name.

I have tried both **prefer-ip-address** and **eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true** properties. None of those worked for me.

Here is my eureka service application .yml file.

[image]

This is my Authorization-server micro-service application.yml

[image]

But still eureka console showing my services registered with host name(localhost) instead of IP address

[image]

I am using Spring boot 2.2.2 version and Spring cloud Hoxton.RELEASE. I am guessing the properties aren't working properly.

Is anyone experiencing the same problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I am on mobile so do not see everything clearly but seems like a problem In declaration

Correct syntax is

```
 eureka.instance.preferIpAddress
```

Whereas  you are using

```
 eureka.instance.prefer-Ip-Address
```

See documentation: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/a7398842078319dcaa353a708c12bb7b9fa85a4e/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-netflix.adoc#prefer-ip-address

eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true will make instance register to Eureka server with IP address. You do not need to provide IP address in any configuration as that will be automatically picked up from system by the application.

In worst case scenario you can define specific IP address.

if you set either the eureka.instance.hostname or the eureka.instance.ipAddress those will always be used in the EurekaInstanceConfigBean so if those are not making it to the server in the registration we need to look at how it is used to build the InstanceInfo.

Comment: Hi @Kunal Vohra, i tried  eureka.instance.preferIpAddress previously also. But same result.

Comment: Can you put a debug point on EurekaInstanceConfigBean and see what is passed on startup.

Comment: I debugged it. It's clearly returning IP address from the below method 

@Override
 public String getHostName(boolean refresh) {
  if (refresh && !this.hostInfo.override) {
   this.ipAddress = this.hostInfo.getIpAddress();
   this.hostname = this.hostInfo.getHostname();
  }
  return this.preferIpAddress ? this.ipAddress : this.hostname;
 }

Means that the property is working.But in Eureka console still i can see localhost of instead of IP

Comment: do you know any reason why it's not showing in the eureka dashboard ?

Comment: Well last attempt is do a cache refresh of your browser. 

Or try on your browser Ctrl+shift+R

Comment: Are you on docker?

Comment: @KunalVohra I think this approach is on docker. Otherwise, it should be working fine when we set the eureka.instance.preferIpAddress. Do you have any suggestions? In case if the developer runs on bridge network mode.

Comment: @Kunal Vohra I am not using docker here. Just ran the two services on my IDE. But facing this issue on AWS also. I just recreated the scenario on my PC.

Comment: I am sorry. I can’t think of any other thing here. Did you try defining custom ip as I mentioned in above comments?? @codeWalter

Comment: @Thilinq Viraj for docker we have one additional step.

Comment: @KunalVohra what's that for docker?

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47781153/10915384

Comment: @codeWalter can you try ’’’’eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
eureka.instance.ip-address=192.168.x.x ’’’’

Comment: I figured it out @ Kunal Vohra. Thanks for ur help. preferIpAddress property is working properly. But in the status section it's not showing the IP address. When i hover over the mouse on the instance, in the bottom left corner i can see the changed IP.

Answer (score 5):

Finally i figured out where i can see **preferIpAddress** property changes. Hover your mouse to instance. Then in the bottom left corner you can see the IP.

Before applying property **preferIpAddress = true**

[image]

After applying property **preferIpAddress = true**

[image]

Comment: How Could I do to get the IP address of the service from another one using LoadBalancerClient?

Comment: What purpose you need the IP address ?

Comment: Actually I need the IP of the Docker machine. I need the docker machne ip address for a service that sends emails. It has to send emails with some URLs related wth other services. How can I do to pass the Docker machine ip address to the emailService?

Comment: You should use a service registry for this kind of scenarios. It's not good practice to call services like that.